# To add a row and create a new records inside a lightning datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

When i try to add new row and create a records in the lightning datatable, its not able to add and create the records. i will share the html code and js code

```
 <div class="slds-var-p-around_small">
            <template if:true={data}>
                <c-l-w-c-custom-datatable-type
                    key-field="Id"
                    data={data}
                    columns={columns}
                    onvalueselect={handleSelection}
                    draft-values={draftValues}
                    oncellchange={handleCellChange}
                    onsave={handleSave}
                    oncancel={handleCancel}
                    hide-checkbox-column>
                </c-l-w-c-custom-datatable-type>
            </template>
        </div>
```

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire , api } from 'lwc';
import fetchAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/CaseController.getCases';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Project_Budgets__c';
import TYPE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Project_Budgets__c.Spend_Category_T__c';
import TYPE_DFIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Project_Budgets__c.Spend_Sub_Category_T__c';
import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import { getPicklistValues, getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';

// import {createRecord} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
// import BudName from '@salesforce/schema/Project_Budgets__c.Name';
// import BudLineItemDescription from '@salesforce/schema/Project_Budgets__c.Line_Item_Description__c';
// import BudCaluculationDescription from '@salesforce/schema/Project_Budgets__c.Calculation_Description__c';
// import BudNgoAndIlpDiscussion from '@salesforce/schema/Project_Budgets__c.NGO_and_ILP_Discussion__c';
// import BudQ1 from '@salesforce/schema/Project_Budgets__c.Q1__c';
// import BudQ2 from '@salesforce/schema/Project_Budgets__c.Q2__c';
// import BudQ3 from '@salesforce/schema/Project_Budgets__c.Q3_c';
// import BudQ4 from '@salesforce/schema/Project_Budgets__c.Q4__c';
// import BudFirstHalfBudget from '@salesforce/schema/Project_Budgets__c.First_Half_Amount__c';
// import BudSecondHalfBudget from '@salesforce/schema/Project_Budgets__c.Second_Half_Amount__c';
// import BudTotalAnnualBudget from '@salesforce/schema/Project_Budgets__c.Total_Annual_Budget__c';

const columns = [
    { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', editable: true },
    {
        label: 'Spend_Category_T__c', fieldName: 'Spend_Category_T__c', type: 'picklistColumn', editable: true, typeAttributes: {
            placeholder: 'Choose Type', options: { fieldName: 'pickListOptions' },
            value: { fieldName: 'Spend_Category_T__c' }, // default value for picklist,
            context: { fieldName: 'Id' } // binding account Id with context variable to be returned back
        }
    },
    {
        label: 'Spend_Sub_Category_T__c', fieldName: 'Spend_Sub_Category_T__c', type: 'picklistDColumn', editable: true, typeAttributes: {
            placeholder: 'Choose Type', options: { fieldName: 'pickListDOptions' },
            value: { fieldName: 'Spend_Category_T__c' }, // default value for picklist,
            context: { fieldName: 'Id' } // binding account Id with context variable to be returned back
        }
    },

    { label: 'Line Item Description', fieldName: 'Line_Item_Description__c', type: 'text', editable: true },
    { label: 'Calculation Description', fieldName: 'Calculation_Description__c', type: 'text', editable: true },
    { label: 'NGO and ILP Discussion', fieldName: 'NGO_and_ILP_Discussion__c', type: 'text', editable: true },
    { label: 'Q1', fieldName: 'Q1__c', type: 'currency', editable: true },
    { label: 'Q2', fieldName: 'Q2__c', type: 'currency', editable: true },
    { label: 'Q3', fieldName: 'Q3__c', type: 'currency', editable: true },
    { label: 'Q4', fieldName: 'Q4__c', type: 'currency', editable: true },
    { label: 'First Half Budget', fieldName: 'First_Half_Amount__c', type: 'currency', editable: true },
    { label: 'Second Half Budget', fieldName: 'Second_Half_Amount__c', type: 'currency', editable: true },
    { label: 'Total Annual Budget', fieldName: 'Total_Annual_Budget__c', type: 'currency', editable: true },

]

export default class CustomDatatableDemo extends LightningElement {
    columns = columns;
    showSpinner = false;
    @track data = [];
    @track accountData;
    @track draftValues = [];
    lastSavedData = [];
    @track pickListOptions;
    @track pickListDOptions;


    @api recordId;
    @track records;



    // name='';
    // spendcategory='';
    // spendsubcategory='';
    // lineitemdescription='';
    // calculationdescription='';
    // ngoandilpdiscussion='';
    // q1='';
    // q2='';
    // q3='';
    // q4='';
    // firsthalfbudget='';
    // secondhalfbudget='';
    // totalannualbudget='';


    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT })
    objectInfo;

    //fetch picklist options
    @wire(getPicklistValues, {
        recordTypeId: "$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId",
        fieldApiName: TYPE_FIELD
    })

    wirePickList({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            console.log('Picklist'+data)
            this.pickListOptions = data.values;
            console.log('pickListOptions',this.pickListOptions)
        } else if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    @wire(getPicklistValues, {
        recordTypeId: "$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId",
        fieldApiName: TYPE_DFIELD
    })

    wireDPickList({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            console.log('DPicklist',data.values);
            this.pickListDOptions = data.values;
            console.log('pickListOptions',this.pickListDOptions)
        } else if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    //here I pass picklist option so that this wire method call after above method
    @wire(fetchAccounts, { pickList: '$pickListOptions',pickDList:'pickListDOptions' })
    accountData(result) {
        this.accountData = result;
        if (result.data) {
            this.data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.data));

            this.data.forEach(ele => {
                ele.pickListOptions = this.pickListOptions;
                ele.pickListDOptions=this.pickListDOptions;
            })

            this.lastSavedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data));

        } else if (result.error) {
            this.data = undefined;
        }
    };

    // budgetchangeval(event)
    // {
    //     console.log(event.target.label);
    //     console.log(event.target.value);
    //     if(event.target.label == 'Name')
    //     {
    //         this.name = event.target.value;
    //     }

    //     if(event.target.label == 'Spend_Category_T__c')
    //     {
    //         this.spendcategory = event.target.value;
    //     }

    //     if(event.target.label == 'Spend_Sub_Category_T__c')
    //     {
    //         this.spendsubcategory = event.target.value;
    //     }

    //     if(event.target.label == 'Line Item Description')
    //     {
    //         this.lineitemdescription = event.target.value;
    //     }


    //     if(event.target.label == 'Calculation Description')
    //     {
    //         this.calculationdescription = event.target.value;
    //     }


    //     if(event.target.label == 'NGO and ILP Discussion')
    //     {
    //         this.ngoandilpdiscussion = event.target.value;
    //     }

    //     if(event.target.label == 'Q1')
    //     {
    //         this.q1 = event.target.value;
    //     }

    //     if(event.target.label == 'Q2')
    //     {
    //         this.q2 = event.target.value;
    //     }

    //     if(event.target.label == 'Q3')
    //     {
    //         this.q3 = event.target.value;
    //     }


    //     if(event.target.label == 'Q4')
    //     {
    //         this.q4 = event.target.value;
    //     }


    //     if(event.target.label == 'First Half Budget')
    //     {
    //         this.firsthalfbudget = event.target.value;
    //     }


    //     if(event.target.label == 'Second Half Budget')
    //     {
    //         this.secondhalfbudget = event.target.value;
    //     }


    //     if(event.target.label == 'Total Annual Budget')
    //     {
    //         this.totalannualbudget = event.target.value;
    //     }

    // }

    updateDataValues(updateItem) {
        let copyData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data));

        copyData.forEach(item => {
            if (item.Id === updateItem.Id) {
                for (let field in updateItem) {
                    item[field] = updateItem[field];
                }
            }
        });

        //write changes back to original data
        this.data = [...copyData];
    }

    updateDraftValues(updateItem) {
        let draftValueChanged = false;
        let copyDraftValues = [...this.draftValues];
        //store changed value to do operations
        //on save. This will enable inline editing &
        //show standard cancel & save button
        copyDraftValues.forEach(item => {
            if (item.Id === updateItem.Id) {
                for (let field in updateItem) {
                    item[field] = updateItem[field];
                }
                draftValueChanged = true;
            }
        });

        if (draftValueChanged) {
            this.draftValues = [...copyDraftValues];
        } else {
            this.draftValues = [...copyDraftValues, updateItem];
        }
    }

    //handler to handle cell changes & update values in draft values
//     handleCellChange(event) {
//         //this.updateDraftValues(event.detail.draftValues[0]);
//         // let draftValues = event.detail.draftValues;
//         // draftValues.forEach(ele=>{
//         //     this.updateDraftValues(ele);
//         // })
//         let draftValues = event.detail.draftValues;
//     draftValues.forEach((ele) => {
//       this.updateDraftValues(ele);

//       // Find the row being updated
//       const updatedRow = this.data.find((row) => row.Id === ele.Id);

//       // Update dependent picklist options based on controlling picklist
//       if (ele.hasOwnProperty('Spend_Category_T__c')) {
//         const selectedCategory = ele.Spend_Category_T__c;
//         console.log('selectedCategory',selectedCategory);
//       // Filter dependent picklist options based on the selected category
//       const filteredDOptions = this.pickListDOptions.filter((option) => {
//         // Implement your logic here to filter based on the category
//         return option.value === selectedCategory; // Replace with your filter condition
//        });

//        updatedRow.pickListDOptions = filteredDOptions;
//       }
//     });
//    this.data = [...this.data];
//     }

handleCellChange(event) {
    let draftValues = event.detail.draftValues;
    draftValues.forEach((ele) => {
        this.updateDraftValues(ele);

        const updatedRow = this.data.find((row) => row.Id === ele.Id);

        if (ele.hasOwnProperty('Spend_Category_T__c')) {
            const selectedCategory = ele.Spend_Category_T__c;

            // Filter dependent picklist options based on the selected category
            const filteredDOptions = this.pickListDOptions.filter((option) => {
                // Implement your logic here to filter based on the category
                return option.validFor.includes(this.pickListOptions.findIndex((item) => item.value === selectedCategory));
            });

            // Update only the specific row's dependent picklist options
            updatedRow.pickListDOptions = filteredDOptions;
        }
    });

    // Update only the specific rows that have been modified
    this.data = [...this.data];
}


    handleSave(event) {
        this.showSpinner = true;
        this.saveDraftValues = this.draftValues;
        const recordInputs = this.saveDraftValues.slice().map(draft => {
            const fields = Object.assign({}, draft);
            return { fields };
        });

        // Updateing the records using the UiRecordAPi
        const promises = recordInputs.map(recordInput => updateRecord(recordInput));
        Promise.all(promises).then(res => {
            this.showToast('Success', 'Records Updated Successfully!', 'success', 'dismissable');
            this.draftValues = [];
            return this.refresh();
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            this.showToast('Error', 'An Error Occured!!', 'error', 'dismissable');
        }).finally(() => {
            this.draftValues = [];
            this.showSpinner = false;
        });
    }

    handleCancel(event) {
        //remove draftValues & revert data changes
        this.data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.lastSavedData));
        this.draftValues = [];
    }

    showToast(title, message, variant, mode) {
        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: title,
            message: message,
            variant: variant,
            mode: mode
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }

    // This function is used to refresh the table once data updated
    async refresh() {
        await refreshApex(this.accountData);
    }

    handleAddRow() {
        // Create a new blank row with default values
        const newRow = {
            Id: '', // Generate a unique identifier if needed
            Name: '',
            Spend_Category_T__c: '', // Blank value for picklist
            Spend_Sub_Category_T__c: '', // Blank value for picklist
            Line_Item_Description__c: '',
            Calculation_Description__c: '',
            NGO_and_ILP_Discussion__c: '',
            Q1__c: '',
            Q2__c: '',
            Q3__c: '',
            Q4__c: '',
            First_Half_Amount__c: '',
            Second_Half_Amount__c: '',
            Total_Annual_Budget__c: '',
            pickListOptions: this.pickListOptions, // Assign picklist options
            pickListDOptions: this.pickListDOptions, // Assign picklist options
        };

        // Add the new row to the data array
        this.data = [...this.data, newRow];

        // Update draft values if needed
        this.draftValues = [...this.draftValues, newRow];
    }
}
```

when i try to add the new row its added but its not showing the dependent picklist values, it has shown all the picklist values and not able to insert the records also while am saving the records into the database.